Firebase 2FA SMS auth/operation-not-allowed
so I have a react app with firebase auth and I'm trying to implement 2FA via SMS (and TOTP but that works as expected).
Whenever I'm trying to send the 2fa enroll sms I get the following error:
auth/operation-not-allowed
This doesn't make sense to me as Email/Password and Phone are enabled as Sign-in providers and SMS multi-factor authentication is also enabled and it is working when I put in a test number. The only time it doesn't work is when I try to enter my own phone's phone number.
I also don't have any regions that are enabled or disabled in the SMS region policy menu.
This is the function that's supposed to trigger the sms sending:
async function sendSignUp2FASMS({
  mobileNumber,
  recaptcha,
}: SmsMfaSetupDTO): Promise<string> {
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  if (!recaptcha) {
    throw new Error('You must use this operation with a recaptcha');
  }

  if (!user) {
    throw new Error('You need to be authenticated in order to continue');
  }

  const session = await multiFactor(user).getSession();

  const phoneInfoOptions = {
    phoneNumber: mobileNumber,
    session,
  };

  const mobileAuthProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth);

  return await mobileAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber( // this is where I get the error
    phoneInfoOptions,
    recaptcha
  );
}

I copied this code over from another project and the configuration on the console is also copied from the other project so I have no clue what I'm doing wrong because there it's working properly.
I tried disabling and then reenabling every provider, including 2fa sms. I also tried deleting them and the readding them.
Any insights are appreciated.
I'm using "firebase": "^10.12.5"
ETA: I verify user emails before getting to the send sms screen.
ETA2: I also sign in before getting to the send sms screen.
